# Stack Overflow for Teams admin settings page failure for several hours

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, error-message

I am trying to access my admin/settings page (https://stackoverflow.com/c/{my_team}/admin/settings) for my team and I receive a generic error (https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/admin/settings/theme):

[image: Private team settings]

[image: Admin settings error]

I have seen this error in the past and it was typically solved in matter of minutes, but now I see the it for a few hours.

What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for your report. This has now been fixed. We just shipped a new feature allowing Team admins to change their Team slug/url and missed a null check on the settings page. The error only impacted Teams on some specific states, which is why we didn't catch it sooner. Should be working now.